# Unable to provide maxdate option for datepicker in mootools

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, mootools

I am using [Mootools datepicker](http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_datepicker)

I imported the below js files in my html

```
<script src="script/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="script/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="script/Locale.en-US.DatePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="script/Picker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="script/Picker.Attach.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="script/Picker.Date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- <link href="styles/mooStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
 <link href="styles/datepicker_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and used the below code

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new Picker.Date($$('#endDate'),{
        timePicker: false,
        positionOffset: {x: 5, y: 0},
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_bootstrap',
        maxDate: {date: new Date()},
        useFadeInOut: !Browser.ie
    });
});
```

Here endDate is id of a textbox. The datepicker works properly without the maxdate parameter.But when I put this option the datepicker is not working.

Checked using firebug and it says

```
TypeError: options.maxDate.clearTime is not a function

options.maxDate.clearTime();  in Picker.Date.js (line 98)
```

Picker.Date.js is a file that comes alongwith this datepicker  plugin.How may I use this maxdate option in this plugin.

**[NOTE:]** please don't suggest jquery datepicker as a solution cause I want resolution for mootools.

Comment: which datepicker is it? is it Arian's http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_datepicker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it just doesn't expect the `{date: ...}` object around the `Date`:

```
// ...
    maxDate: new Date(),
// ...
```

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/arian/mootools-datepicker/blob/master/README.md#class-datepicker), only a few types are expected for the value:

> maxDate: (*Date instance*, *string*, defaults to `null`) [...]